# Book about someone using hackers and spiders to find information

Tags: story-identification

I read this book 4+ years ago, but I can only remember some of it:

Someone was looking for information about something specific and had a spider (a bot that will search the web e.g. Google bot) written and it searched everything online and eventually found a copy of it, but couldn't access it due to it being in some digital vault. She had no problem paying for the information, but couldn't find the owner(?), so she asked a hacker to try to hack into it. The hacker went about trying to hack into it, but he was amazed at it due to the complexity of it and never seen anything like that before. Not too long later he got a call from the CIA asking him what was he doing.

The above isn't the full plot to the story, but it ties into it and it's all that I can remember of it. I know it is a bit vague.

Comment: @Politank-Z, I clarified it a bit (I hope).

Comment: I hate to say this, but did it have any fantasy or sci-fi elements to it?

Comment: @SeanDuggan I'm couldn't say for 100% it is, but I am fairly sure it is. I mostly just read fantasy/sci-fi books until a few years ago.

Comment: Don't hacking/bots fall under sci-fi?

Comment: @sudhanva - No, because that's simply a part of normal reality. It may be fiction, but today it's no longer science fiction. If the OP could say it was written in, say, 1960, before the Internet existed, then it might be science fiction.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the clarification @RDFozz

Comment: @RDFozz I totally forgot about this question and I had found the book a few years ago by mistake. It's called The Lost Symbol by Dan Brown. I'm not 100% sure if it would be classified as Sci-fi.